# How to change AMPscript logic such that it results in a one-click unsubscribe?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, unsubscribe

```
    %%[
/*AMPSCRIPT PROCESSING GOES HERE*/

/*GRAB SUBSCRIBER INFO*/
SET @email = RequestParameter('emailaddr')
SET @subKey = RequestParameter('_subscriberkey')
SET @result = RequestParameter('result')
SET @businessName = RequestParameter('businessName')
SET @emailName = RequestParameter('emailName')
SET @jobID = RequestParameter('jobID')
SET @businessID = RequestParameter('businessID')
SET @error = 'false'

IF empty(@email) OR empty(@subKey) THEN
 SET @error = 'true'
ELSE
 /*GET SUBSCRIBER'S CURRENT INFO, CHECK ALL SUBS FIRST, THEN CHECK SF RECORDS BECAUSE A PERSON MAY NOT HAVE EVER RECEIVED AN EMAIL*/
 SET @status = Lookup("_subscribers", "status" , "EmailAddress", @email, "SubscriberKey", @subKey)
ENDIF

/*IS THIS A SF CONTACT?*/
IF IndexOf(@subKey, ".com") < 0 then
  IF RowCount(RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id', 'email', '=', @email)) >= 1 AND Rowcount(RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id', 'id', '=', @subKey)) >= 1 THEN
   SET @isSFContact = 'true'
  ELSE
   SET @isSFContact = 'false'
  ENDIF
ENDIF

/*WAS A BUTTON CLICKED? IF NOT, ASSUME IT'S A FIRST VISIT*/
IF empty(@result) THEN
 SET @default = 'true'
ELSE
 SET @default = 'false'
ENDIF

/*UNSUB HANDLING*/
IF @default == 'false' THEN

  /*ENSURE WE HAVE A SUBSCRIBER KEY AND EMAIL, OTHERWISE ERROR*/
  IF NOT EMPTY(@subKey) AND NOT EMPTY(@email) THEN

    SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @subKey)
    
    /*DETERMINE IF THIS IS AN UNSUB OR RESUB*/
    IF @result == 'unsubscribe' THEN
     SET @action = "Opt-Out"
     SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", "Unsubscribed")
     IF @isSFContact == 'true' THEN   
      SET @sfUpdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@subKey,'HasOptedOutOfEmail','true')
     ENDIF
    ELSEIF @result == 'resubscribe' THEN
     SET @action = "Resubscribe"
     SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", "Active")    
       IF @isSFContact == 'true' THEN
        SET @sfUpdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@subKey,'HasOptedOutOfEmail','false')
       ENDIF    
    ENDIF

    /*UPDATE CALL*/
    SET @updateCall = InvokeUpdate(@sub) 
    IF @updateCall == "OK" THEN
      SET @error = 'false'
      SET @success = 'true'
    ELSE
      SET @error = 'true'
    ENDIF
     
    
    /*LOGGING*/
   SET @insertRecord = insertData("ENT.Preference_Center_Log",'EmailAddress', @email,'SubscriberKey', @subKey, 'action', @action, 'date',Now(), 'job_id', @jobID, 'email_name', @emailName, 'businessName', @businessName, 'MID',@businessID)
  ELSE
    SET @error = 'true'
  ENDIF
ENDIF


/*DEBUGGING, DISABLE WHEN LIVE*/
SET @debug = 'false'

IF @debug == 'true' then
 output(concat('<h4>Debugging values, this will be removed at launch.</h4>',
 'Email: ', @email, '<br>',
 'SubKey: ', @subKey, '<br>',
 'result: ', @result, '<br>',
 'error: ', @error, '<br>',
 'unsubCall: ', @updateCall, '<br>',
 'Subscriber Status: ', @status, '<br>',
 'email name: ', @emailName, '<br>',
 'BusinessID: ', @businessID, '<br>',
 'jobID: ', @jobID, '<br>',
 'success: ', @success, '<br>',
 'default: ', @default,'<br>',
 'SF Contact: ', @isSFContact))
ENDIF


]%%


<script runat="server">
  
  }
  catch(err){
   Write(Stringify(err)) 
  }
  
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABCD
    </title>
    <!-- End Tab Title -->
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,500);
      @import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
      /* CHANGE FORM-BUMP TO MOVE FORM UP OR DOWN */
      .form-bump {
        margin-top: -300px;
      }
      * {
        font-family: "Roboto",Arial,sans-serif;
      }
      img.logo {
        width: 224px;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 2.8em;
        margin: .1em 0 .25em;
        line-height: 1.1em;
        letter-spacing: .01em;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 2.241em;
        line-height: 1;
        margin-bottom: 0.2em;
      }
      .form-header {
        background-color: #002957;
      }
      .error {
        color: #AD122A;
        /*  font-weight: 700;*/
      }
      p, li {
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
      .bg-nm {
        background-color: #AD122A
      }
      .per-95 {
        width: 90%;
      }
      @media all and (max-width: 992px) {
        .form-bump {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 2.5em;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
  </head>
<body>
   <section class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <img src="" class="logo mt-3 mb-3" />
      </div>
   </section>
   <div class="bg-nm">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 mt-5 mb-5 mr-1">
               %%[/*THROW ERROR*/
                  IF @error == 'true' THEN]%%
               <div class="text-white per-95">
                  <h1>We're sorry 
                  </h1>
                  <p>An error has occured. Please contact reply@.com for help.
                  </p>
               </div>
                         
               %%[/*USER TOOK ACTION*/
                  ELSEIF @error == 'false' AND @success == 'true' THEN]%%
              
              %%[/*RESUBSCRIBE SUCCESS*/
                 IF @result == 'resubscribe' THEN]%%
              
               <div class="text-white per-95">
                  <h1>You are resubscribed. 
                  </h1>
                  <p>You have opted back in to emails%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@businessName) THEN]%%&nbsp;from %%=v(@businessName)=%%%%[ENDIF]%%.
                  </p>
               </div>
              
              %%[/*UNSUB SUCCESS*/ 
                  ELSEIF @result == 'unsubscribe' THEN]%%
                <div class="text-white per-95">
                  <h1>Thank you. 
                  </h1>
                  <p>You will no longer receive email messages. <small>Please note: </small>
                  </p>
               </div>
              %%[ENDIF]%%
              %%[/*SUBSCRIBER ALREADY UNSUBBED*/
                ELSEIF @error == 'false' AND @status == 'unsubscribed' AND @default == 'true' THEN]%%
               <div class="text-white per-95">
                  <h1>You are already opted-out 
                  </h1>
                  <p>If you believe this was done in error, please contact reply@.com.
                  </p>
                 <p>If you would like to resubscribe your email: %%=v(@email)=%% to all %%[IF NOT EMPTY(@businessName) THEN]%%%%=v(@businessName)=%% related%%[ENDIF]%% emails, click resubscribe below.
                  </p>
                 <form action="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(8290, 'result', 'resubscribe', 'emailaddr', @email, '_subscriberkey', @subkey, 'emailName', @emailName, 'businessName', @businessName, 'jobID', @jobID, 'businessID', @businessID))=%%" method="POST">
                     <input class="btn btn-light btn-lg me-3" type="submit" name="resub" id="resub" value="Resubscribe">
                     
                  </form>
               </div> 
               %%[/*DEFAULT VIEW*/
                  ELSE]%%
              %%[ENDIF]%%
               <div class="text-white per-95">
                  <h1>Unsubscribe? 
                  </h1>
                  <p>Would you like to unsubscribe your email: %%=v(@email)=%% from all %%[IF NOT EMPTY(@businessName) THEN]%%%%=v(@businessName)=%% related%%[ENDIF]%% emails?
                  </p>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <form action="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(8290, 'result', 'unsubscribe', 'emailaddr', @email, '_subscriberkey', @subkey, 'emailName', @emailName, 'businessName', @businessName, 'jobID', @jobID, 'businessID', @businessID))=%%" method="POST">
                     <input class="btn btn-light btn-lg me-3" type="submit" name="unsub" id="unsub" value="Unsubscribe">
                     <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" type="submit" formaction="https://www.nebraskamed.com/" formmethod="POST">
                     Nevermind
                     </button></a>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   <!-- Form -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="%%=CloudPagesURL(7588)=%%"></script>     
</body>
<!--RegionEnd[socialslot:"allcontent"]-->
</html>
```

We're moving to a one-click unsubscribe and would like to get rid of the additional step that ask whether the user would like to unsubscribe. Instead, when Unsubscribe is clicked on from the email header or footer, it should automatically display "Thank you...". The rest of the views; Error and Resubscribe should work the same way however.

I've tried multiple things but can't seem to get the logic working correctly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you need to implement this? I assume this is coming out of the “hyped” requirements by Yahoo and Google. There is some confusion on what “one click unsubscribe” actually refers to. It doesn’t need to be a custom solution, as it is already supported by SFMC, which appends list-unsubscribe header to all commercial sends.

Here is an article explaining the “one click unsubscribe” term: https://wordtothewise.com/2024/01/one-click-unsubscribe/

It should of course not prevent you from doing what you are about to do, but the above clarification might save you some work.

Comment: You're right, there's been alot of confusion around this topic. Thanks for clarifying.